# magento Totals on Cart / Sort order not working

Tags: php, magento

When want to have the following style of totals on checkout/cart:

```
(1) Discount
(2) Subtotal
(3) Shipping fee OR Info Text: "excl. shipping"
(4) Additional text: "free shipping from 30EUR" (display always)
(5) Grand total
(6) incl. Tax
```

Problems

(1)  Even if we set "Checkout Totals Sort Order" in the backend correctly, the grand total is always displayed at the end

(2)  How to put any additional info blocks between the totals?
   (3)  How to display an info text, if one total is not present (shipping)

Answer (score 0):

GOTO `theme->default->template->checkout->cart->totals.phtml`

and `theme->default->template->tax->checkout` files are responsible for this. Dig the code there.